# How do you earn Swarm Points with Wings of Liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have an account with just Wings of Liberty on it, but my profile tells me that I'm a level 2 Terran (though I generally play Protoss). How is this possible? I'm just restarting the game so I can't remember when I've earned xp.

I've heard about the *Spawning System* that allows a friend who has HOTS to share their licence with others members of the group, perhaps that is the explanation?

Comment: Where do you see two questions (Here is the second) ? Just want to know how to earn swarm points with Wings of Liberty expansion. My english is not perfect and I might expressed myself badly, the downvotes are here slightly severe :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have HoT's installed? 
That might be the answer, because blizzard on special occasions gives players full access to the game, like with purchased version. If you whant to check in which version you are, if I remember right go to Options -> GamePlay And in top right should be option to switch between WoL and Hot's.

And yea Spawning pool system is from brood war times, it is system to let play games with your friends which don't have SC2 hot's.

Comment: Basically Starcraft install the last update, so HoTs, but accounts with only WoL don't have access to the new features like the Swarm Points